# How to call a Grails service in a view?

Tags: grails, service, view, gsp

Simple question :
I have a service class (let's say `helpersService`) and a method `def constructURI(params)`.
How can I call this method from a template view.

I have tried the following code without success

```
<% def helpersService  = new HelpersService() // or def helpersService
%>
<img src="${helpersService. constructURI(params)}"/>
```

But I get the following result:

```
No signature of method: com.HelpersService. constructURI() is applicable for argument types...
```

or (in case I use `def helpersService`)

```
Cannot invoke method constructURI() on null object
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510929/how-do-i-call-a-grails-service-from-a-gsp/19378586#19378586

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Services are not intended to be used inside views. You could create a TagLib where you can get a reference to the service via dependency injection.

Comment: Yes, taglibs are so much cleaner all the way around

Comment: see also question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510929/problem-calling-grails-service-from-gsp

taglib example:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7005752/160799
(looks not very clean to me, though. I prefer solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/1652410/160799 below - still new to Grails but I found no other way for handling display based on access rights for items in a search result list).

Answer (score 7):

An easier method, assuming your view is being rendered by a Controller, is to just pass a reference to the service from the action to the view within the model, i.e.:

```
class someController {
  def someService
  def someAction = {
    render(view: 'someView', model: ['someService': someService])
  }
}
```

It can then be used as you would expect within the view. For a template rendered by a view, obviously you need to pass the reference to the template as well. Just to be clear though, S. Puchbauer is right; services are not really supposed to be used within Views, and you may experience difficult to diagnose problems, especially related to transactions and the Hibernate session.

Answer (score 2):

I found out, that this groovy inline code works:

```
<% def xxxService = application.getAttribute("org.codehaus.groovy.grails.APPLICATION_CONTEXT").getBean("xxxService") %>
```

You can call functions of the service just like this:

```
<g:select optionKey="key" from="${xxxService.getWhateverList()}" name="tarif" value="${accountInstance?.tarif}" ></g:select>
```

Comment: I've used this in a pinch in a universal header view, since every page will need it

Comment: Just from the code it is pretty evident that this is not a good pattern to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have found a workaround with the following code :

```
def helpersService = grailsApplication.classLoader.loadClass('HelpersService').newInstance()
```

However it is better to use Service via dependency injection, so I will try out Siegfried advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily without creating a tag lib by using the set tag:

```
<g:set var="versionService" bean="versionService"/>
...
<p>version ${versionService.clientVersion}</p>
```

I found this solution here: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/08/grails-goodness-use-services-in-gsp.html