# How to import a service that is in a package into a gsp file in Grails

Tags: grails, service, import, gsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem calling grails service from gsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510929/problem-calling-grails-service-from-gsp)

I have a service called HeaderService that is in a package called application in a project called Portfolio. How can i import this service into a gsp? I have tried

```
<%@ page import="com.portfolio.application.HeaderService" %>
```

And many variations, but It doesnt work. Anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Using a service in a GSP is generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access your services through the `applicationContext` object that's implicitly available in views.  Example:

```
<%= applicationContext.headerService.doSomething() %>
```

Comment: Great, you told him how to do something horrible.

Comment: I agree with your comment that it's bad practice.  Fine.  It's still useful to know how to do it.  Sometimes, it's a convenient shortcut; a great example is the default `index.gsp` grails generates with `create-app` which uses this technique to get access to the `pluginManager`.